# Insert Data with ticked to enable input label

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have create simple data insertion page where user first ticked to enable input label & submit to insert into db.But now problem is data not inserting into db it shows error"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`life`, `joyy`, `epic`,`storm`,`fusion`,`elite`, `exite`, `style`, `infinity`, `' at line 1".
Secondly it shows undefined index error if user click submit button without  ticked to select input label.
Please help me someone find out the solution

```
<div align="center"> 
    <H1 align="center" class="header">SIS Live Demo Delivery </H1>
        <form   method="post">
            <table  width="620px" border="2" bordercolor="#FFCC00" align="center" 
                cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
            <tr align="centre" style="border-spacing:">
                <td width="20%" align="left"><div align="left"> Dated:</div></td>
                <td width="26%"><input type="date" name="ddate"/></td>
                <td width="19%">Retailer Id:</td>
                <td width="35%">
                    <select style=" width:142px;" name="agentid" size="1"ID="ddlList">
                        <option value="">Select Retailer</option>
                        <?php foreach ( $results as $option ) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $option['Agentid']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $option['Agentid']; ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Recived By</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="rcvrname" /></td>
                <td>Deliver By:</td>
                <td>
                    <select style=" width:142px;" name="deliverby">
                        <option value="">Select Name</option>
                        <option value="">Anisur Rahman</option>
                    </select>
                </td><
            /tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="life" value=""name="life"> Life</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="life_imei" name="life" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off">
                </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="joy"> Joy</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="joyy" id="joy_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="epic" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No"> Epic
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"id="epic_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15"
                        autocomplete="off" name="epic">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" onclick="storm" id="storm" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No">Storm
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="storm" id="storm_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" onclick="fusion"id="fusion" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No"> Fusion
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="fusion"id="fusion_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" onclick="elite" id="elite"
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No"> Elite
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="elite"id="elite_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="exite" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No"> Exite
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="exite" id="exite_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="style" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No"> Style
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="style" id="style_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=others
                        onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" id="infinity" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" /> Infinity
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="infinity" id="infinity_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="magic" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No"> Magic
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="magic" id="magic_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="inspire" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15  IMEI No"> Inspire
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="inspire" id="inspire_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="innova"
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No"> Innova
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="innova" id="innova_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="sensation" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No"> Sensation
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="sensation" id="sensation_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off" />
                </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="magicc"> Striker</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="magicc" id="magicc_imei" 
                        placeholder="Insert 15 digit IMEI No" maxlength="15" 
                        autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Note:</td>
                <td><textarea name="note" id="note"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <th height="32" bgcolor="#FFFF66">
                <input CausesValidation="true" name="submit" 
                  size="170" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php echo isset($insert_status)?$insert_status:''?> 
    </form>
</div>



<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            echo 'Hello';
            $life = "";
            if(isset($_POST['life'])){
                $life = $_POST['life'];
            }
            $joyy = "";
            if(isset($_POST['joyy'])){
                $joyy = $_POST['joyy'];
            }
            $epic = "";
            if(isset($_POST['epic'])){
                $epic = $_POST['epic'];
            }
            $storm = "";
            if(isset($_POST['storm'])){
                $storm = $_POST['storm'];
            }
            $fusion = "";
            if(isset($_POST['fusion'])){
                $fusion = $_POST['fusion'];
            }
            $elite = "";
            if(isset($_POST['elite'])){
                $elite = $_POST['elite'];
            }
            $exite = "";
            if(isset($_POST['exite'])){
                $exite = $_POST['exite'];
            }
            $style = "";
            if(isset($_POST['style'])){
                $style = $_POST['style'];
            }
            $infinity = "";
            if(isset($_POST['infinity'])){
                $infinity = $_POST['infinity'];
            }
            $magic = "";
            if(isset($_POST['magic'])){
                $magic = $_POST['magic'];
            }
            $inspire = "";
            if(isset($_POST['inspire'])){
                $inspire = $_POST['inspire'];
            }
            $innova = "";
            if(isset($_POST['innova'])){
                $innova = $_POST['innova'];
            }
            $sensation = "";
            if(isset($_POST['sensation'])){
                $sensation = $_POST['sensation'];
            }
            $magicc = "";
            if(isset($_POST['magicc'])){
                $magicc = $_POST['magicc'];
            }

            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","myapps");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            $sql="INSERT INTO `sales` (
                    `ddate`, `agentidH`, `rcvrname`, `deliverby`, `note` `life`,
                    `joyy`, `epi`, `storm`, `fusion`, `elite`, `exite`, `style`,
                    `infinity`, `magic`, `inspire`, `innova`, `sensation`,
                    `magicc`
            ) VALUES(
                '$_POST[ddate]','$_POST[agentid]','$_POST[rcvrname]',
                '$_POST[deliverby]','$_POST[note]','$_POST[life]',
                '$_POST[joyy]','$_POST[epic]','$_POST[storm]',
                '$_POST[elite]','$_POST[exite]', '$_POST[style]',
                '$_POST[infinity]','$_POST[magic]','$_POST[inspire]',
                '$_POST[innova]','$_POST[sensation]','$_POST[magicc]'
            )";

            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            $insert_status="Insert Successfull";
            header("refresh:4;url=index.php" );
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
?>

<!--Java Script to enable input label -->
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var update_life = function ()
    {
        if ($("#life").is(":checked")) {
            $('#life_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#life_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_life);
    $("#life").change(update_life);

    //--------------Joy----------------
    var update_joy = function ()
    {
        if ($("#joy").is(":checked")) {
            $('#joy_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#joy_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };

    $(update_joy);
    $("#joy").change(update_joy);
    $(update_life);
    $("#life").change(update_life);

    //--------------Epic----------------
    var update_epic = function ()
    {
        if ($("#epic").is(":checked"))
        {
            $('#epic_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#epic_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_epic);
    $("#epic").change(update_epic);

    //--------------Storm----------------
    var update_storm = function ()
    {
        if ($("#storm").is(":checked")) {
            $('#storm_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#storm_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_storm);
    $("#storm").change(update_storm);

    //--------------fusion----------------
    var update_fusion = function ()
    {
        if ($("#fusion").is(":checked")) {
            $('#fusion_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#fusion_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_fusion);
    $("#fusion").change(update_fusion);

    //--------------Elite----------------
    var update_elite = function ()
    {
        if ($("#elite").is(":checked"))
        {
            $('#elite_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#elite_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_elite);
    $("#elite").change(update_elite);

    //--------------Exite----------------
    var update_exite = function ()
    {
        if ($("#exite").is(":checked")) {
            $('#exite_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#exite_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_exite);
    $("#exite").change(update_exite);

    //--------------Style----------------
    var update_style = function () {
        if ($("#style").is(":checked")) {
            $('#style_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#style_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_style);
    $("#style").change(update_style);

    //--------------Infinity----------------
    var update_infinity = function () {
        if ($("#infinity").is(":checked")) {
                $('#infinity_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#infinity_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_infinity);
    $("#infinity").change(update_infinity);

    //--------------Magic---------------- 
    var update_magic= function () {
        if ($("#magic").is(":checked")) {
            $('#magic_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#magic_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_magic);
    $("#magic").change(update_magic); 

    //--------------Inspire ---------------- 
    var update_inspire= function () {
        if ($("#inspire").is(":checked")) {
            $('#inspire_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#inspire_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_inspire);
    $("#inspire").change(update_inspire);

    //-------------- Innova ---------------- 
    var update_innova= function () {
        if ($("#innova").is(":checked")) {
            $('#innova_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#innova_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_innova);
    $("#innova").change(update_innova);

    //-------------- Innova ---------------- 
    var update_sensation= function () {
        if ($("#sensation").is(":checked")) {
            $('#sensation_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#sensation_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_sensation);
    $("#sensation").change(update_sensation);

    //-------------- Innova ---------------- 
    var update_magicc= function () {
        if ($("#magicc").is(":checked")) {
            $('#magicc_imei').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#magicc_imei').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };
    $(update_magicc);
    $("#magicc").change(update_magicc);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please give more code? I think that's really not enough. More lines! More lines!

Comment: what parts of code u need

Comment: The problematic part, of course. You can't just say "Help me" and vomit 1000 lines of code. Narrow down your problem, make a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
  echo 'Hello';
  $life = "";
  if(isset($_POST['life'])){
   $life = $_POST['life'];

Comment: @AnisurRahman For you next post, please have an eye for the readabilty of your text. It was a lot of work to improve the readability of this one.

Comment: When did this wall of code stop working? Or did you expect it to work first time? When coding you should take small steps, and perform testing after each step. This is preferable to writing a lot of code that doesn’t work, followed by a long 

debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It appears that you miss-spelled magicc in your INSERT STATEMENT, fix that.  Miss-spell is in the POST variable.  $_POST[magicc]** ALSO, When passing sql via php, its good to add a space in front and at the end of the query.  Before the INSERT and after the closing ) example:

```
$sql=" INSERT INTO `sales` (
                    `ddate`, `agentidH`, `rcvrname`, `deliverby`, `note` `life`,
                    `joyy`, `epi`, `storm`, `fusion`, `elite`, `exite`, `style`,
                    `infinity`, `magic`, `inspire`, `innova`, `sensation`,
                    `magicc`
            ) VALUES(
                '$_POST[ddate]','$_POST[agentid]','$_POST[rcvrname]',
                '$_POST[deliverby]','$_POST[note]','$_POST[life]',
                '$_POST[joyy]','$_POST[epic]','$_POST[storm]',
                '$_POST[elite]','$_POST[exite]', '$_POST[style]',
                '$_POST[infinity]','$_POST[magic]','$_POST[inspire]',
                '$_POST[innova]','$_POST[sensation]','$_POST[magicc]'
            ) ";
```

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO `sales`( `ddate`, `agentid`, `rcvrname`, `deliverby`, `note`, `life`, `joyy`, `epic`, `storm`, `fusion`, `elite`, `exite`, `style`, `infinity`, `magic`, `inspire`, `innova`, `sensation`, `striker`) 
VALUES(
`$ddate`, `$agentid`, `$rcvrname`, `$deliverby`, `$note`,
`$life`, `$joyy`, `$epic`, `$storm`, `$fusion`, `$elite`,
`$exite`, `$style`, `$infinity`, `$magic`, `$inspire`, `$innova`, `$sensation, `$striker`)";

Comment: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , , , , , , , , , , , , , )' at line 6

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
  echo 'Hello';
  $ddate = '';
  if(isset($_POST['ddate'])){
   $ddate = $_POST['ddate'];
  }
  $agentid = '';
  if(isset($_POST['agentid'])){
   $agentid = $_POST['agentid'];
  }
  $rcvrname = '';
  if(isset($_POST['rcvrname'])){
   $rcvrname = $_POST['rcvrname'];
  }